# Samples for Junit testing with Spring framework and mongodb

Tags: spring-mvc, junit, mongodb-java

I need to do a junit testing for my spring application and it is done with mongo database.
I have no previous experience in embedding the junit testing with spring and mongodb.
Any reply, will great helpful to me...

Thanks with Regards.

Comment: Thanks Steven for the Reply, i am not ever done any testing like automation's. At still i done only manual testing. Actually i am surfing for some examples to do junit testing in spring framework architecture with mongodatabase or any database. How to start implementing the junit testing, how to check the controller/service layers, how to do database testing for add/edit/delete values etc.,

Comment: @lk.annamalai If the answer was helpful to you, I'd appreciate if you mark it as accepted. That will help me and others with a similar problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking at the JUnit documentation, specifically, I would start with [Assertions](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Assertions).  When testing with a dependency injection framework (e.g. Spring) a mocking framework is essential.  Check out [EasyMock](http://www.easymock.org/) or [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/).

Answer (score 0):

I use Spring mongo template in a Spring MVC app and JUnit 4.8.2 for unit tests.
Just create a bean for your mongoTemplate and use Autowired to inject it in your classes. As for the tests, follow these steps:

1.Create a new JUnit test case (right-click on your class in the Package Explorer, then new->JUnit Test Case). It will create a test method for each method of your class you specify.

2.Now you'll have your tests at *src/test/java* and yor resources at *src/test/resources*. It is better if you create a spring config file just for the tests so you can point the tests to a local mongodb instance and your application to perhaps a Development mongoDB instance. So create a the config file at *src/test/resources* and name it *testSpringConfig.xml* or whatever and create the bean there:

```
    <mongo:db-factory dbname="myDB"  host="localhost" 
    username="myDbUser" password="myPass"/>    

    <beans:bean id="mongoTemplate"   
    class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="mongoTemplateLibrary"    
    class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
```

3.In your test class, use annotations to reference your config file:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/testSpringConfig.xml"})
public class MyDaoTest {
```

4.Once you have your test class set up, inject the mongo template

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("mongoTemplate")
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
```

5.Now yo can use it to insert/remove/find/update directly to mongo (although this would be a integration test more than a unit test)
For example, you can remove the objects you inserted in your tests using the Tear Down method:

```
@After
public void tearDown() {
    mongoTemplate.remove(myObject);
}
```

Comment: Hi AntonioOtero, Thanks for your Reply. Let me try this and let you know the updated shortly.

Answer (score 0):

pom.xml file Config as follows,

```
<properties>
    ....
    <junit.version>4.10</junit.version>
    ....
</properties>
<dependencies>
    .....
    <!-- Test dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version><!-- JUNIT CHANGES -->
        <scope>test</scope>         
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
        <version>1.26</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>            

    <!-- Mockito --><!-- JUNIT MOCKITO DEPENDENCY ADDED -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Mockito -->
     ......
</dependencies>
<build>
      ....
      <plugins>
          ......
           <!-- JUNIT PLUGIN CODE ADDED-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.5</source>
              <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.14</version>
            <configuration>
        <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
              <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                <version>2.14</version>
              </dependency>
            </dependencies>
          </plugin>
        <!-- END OF JUINT CODE -->
            .....
      </plugins>
      <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
      <testSourceDirectory>src/test/junit</testSourceDirectory>
</build>....
```

After setting up the pom cofigurations, do the test case code as by the following steps

- Assuming as you are using IDE's like STS or else, just right click on the corresponding class and click on Junit Test Case and create class under the src/test/java path.
- For implementing for spring controller classes first we initialize all the objects like initialize values from the test case code of the corresponding class in the `setUp()` method.
- Then call the corresponding methods from the test case and do the appropriate junit assertion check-in if the corresponding method returns values like string/int/boolean etc.,

Like below:

```
@Test
    public void testSave() {
    MessageValue messageValue = saveController.saveValue(value+"::Test", model);
    Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("value").is("Test").and("_id").is(id));
    SaveValue saveValueThis = template.findOne(query, Save.class);
    assertEquals("Success", messageValue.getMessage());
    // delete the saved value at the end of test case
        testDelete(); 
}
```

If it returns some UI page that is redirection to some other screen then check like below,

```
mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(yourController).build();
    mockMvc.perform(get("/request/url").accept(MediaType.ALL))
    .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

- Finally in the test case `tearDown()` method reset the initialized values.