# MongoDB unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, mongodb, junit, embedded-database, spring-data-mongodb

I have a Spring-based webapp and I am using [Fongo](https://github.com/foursquare/fongo) for some of my Junit tests. This did the trick so far but now I would like to set my database into a concrete context before executing them (by loading, for instance, a .json file beforehand into a concrete collection) and it turns out not to be possible using Fongo. What do you use normally? Is it actually possible? Are there out other possible options? I also heard of [EmbedMongo](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/embedmongo.flapdoodle.de) but I am not sure this works with Spring Data repositories, which is what I am using in the persistence layer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [this](https://github.com/niltz/mongodb-maven-plugin) Maven plugin. It allows populate/update your Mongo database before running your unit tests (it is a Maven plugin). It is probably not the best option but it did at least the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use JUnit 4 and Spring Data's mongoTemplate.
Take a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15801960/samples-for-junit-testing-with-spring-framework-and-mongodb/15884696#15884696) to a similar question.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @AntonioOtero but I am using Spring Data repositories approach and I do not work directly with the mongo template. Thanks anyway for your answer!